# calling JNIEnv::SetByteArrayRegion causes random crash when the bytearray is too big?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm working on a game that runs on android phones using ndk, recently I've come across a crashing problem which I believe is related to calling the JNI function `SetByteArrayRegion`. I've simplified the issue with the following code:

```
char content[18230925];
jbyteArray jdata;
jdata = lpJNIEnv->NewByteArray(18230925);
//lpJNIEnv is a JNIEnv pointer
lpJNIEnv->SetByteArrayRegion(jdata, 0, 18230925, (const jbyte*)content);
```

by running these code I met random crash on android devices when calling

```
lpJNIEnv->SetByteArrayRegion(jdata, 0, 18230925, (const jbyte*)content)
```

by *random* I mean a very big chance,(and even bigger on some certain devices).

I did some experiments and found out it seems to have something to do with the byte array size, if i shrink the size of the buffer to like `182309`, then it won't crash.(and my application has been using a smaller buffer size for a long time and no issue had occurred before...)

I've done all the checking and ruled out all the possible flaws of the application that i can think about(like threading...), so, is there anything wrong about this JNI usage??

Comment: What happens if you allocate the content buffer with malloc instead of allocating it on the stack? 17 MB is quite much to have on the stack.

Comment: yes, originally the code is using buffer on heap, and in that way, on some devices, it won't crash, but on some others, it will crash with a big chance, so, is heap size a problem too?

Comment: so, i wonder is a heap buffer of 17MB too much for some devices to handle? do i have to split the bytes and handle them seperately?

Comment: It's hard to say; if you have a very fragmented virtual memory you might have a hard time to allocate a contiguous 17 MB buffer, but that's probably not your issue. If you're low on memory you might of course run out of memory - in this case you first need 17 MB for the source buffer, then another 17 MB for the java byte array, plus everything else you're running within your process.